# Equation of even multiple of straight line

Tags: analytic-geometry

$$ x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha -p = 0$$ represents a straight line in polar form (or even taken in any other form),

$$ (x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha -p )^3 = 0$$ represents 3 straight lines repeated, but why does not, $ (n\in \mathbb Z) $

$$ ( x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha -p)^{2\,n}  = 0 $$ at all plot for even powers ?  I used *Mathematica* but  other CAS could  be written the same way  in this respect. Why does it not represent evenly repeated straight lines?

Comment: $f(x,y)=0 \iff (f(x,y))^k=0$ for any function $f$ and $k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. It's not clear what you mean by `does not at all plot for even numbers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct issues here: what the equation represents and what plots (on particular software).

For any positive integer $n$, $f(x,y)^n = 0$ has exactly the same solutions as $f(x,y) = 0$.

On typical software programs that use numerical methods, implicit plots depend on detecting sign changes, so they will often miss local minima of $0$.  See e.g. [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942653/wolfram-alpha-doesnt-plot-implicit-function-with-range/1942693)

Comment: Detection succeeds for odd powers and fails for even, right? Also does Maple give repeated $y$ roots for example to solve a simple $ x=1?$ with the evenly repeated straight line?