# Optimizing a quadratic in one variable with parameterized coefficients

Tags: calculus, quadratics

Recently I was doing a physics problem and I ended up with this quadratic in the middle of the steps:

$$ 0= X \tan \theta - \frac{g}{2} \frac{  X^2 \sec^2 \theta }{ (110)^2 } - 105$$

I want to find $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}2$ for which I can later take the largest $X$ value that solves this equation, i.e. optimize the implicit curve to maximize $X$.

I tried solving this by implicit differentiation (assuming $X$ can be written as a function of $\theta$) with respect to $\theta$ and then by setting $\frac{dX}{d\theta} = 0$:

\begin{align}
0 &= X \sec^2 \theta  + \frac{ d X}{ d \theta} \tan \theta - \frac{g}{2} \frac{ 2 \left( X \sec \theta \right) \left[  \frac{dX}{d \theta} \sec \theta + X \sec \theta \tan \theta \right]}{ (110)^2 } - 105 \\
0 &= X  \sec^2 \theta  - \frac{g}{2} \frac{ 2( X \sec \theta) \left[ X \sec \theta \tan \theta\right] }{ (110)^2 } \\
0 &= 1 - \frac{ Xg \tan \theta}{(110)^2} \\
\frac{ (110)^2}{ g \tan \theta} &= X
\end{align}

This is still not an easy equation to solve. However, one of my friends told we could just take the discriminant of the quadratic in terms of $X$, and solve for  $\theta$ such that $D=0$.

Taking discriminant and equating to 0, I get

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{ \sqrt{2 \cdot 10 \cdot 105} }{110}$$

and, the angle from it is, 24.45 degrees

I tried the discriminant method, but it gave me a different answer from the implicit differentiation method. I ended up with two solutions with the same maximum value of $X$ but different angles: $\theta =24.45^\text{o}$ and $X=1123.54$ (from discriminant method), and
$\theta = 47^\text{o}$ and $X=1123.54$ (from implicit differentiation).

I later realized the original quadratic can only have solutions if $D(\theta) > 0$, where $D$ is the discriminant. Using the discriminant, I can find a lower bound on the angle. Once I have the lower bound, if I can prove that $X$ decreases monotonically as a function of $\theta$, then I can use the lower bound for further calculations of $\theta$.

So then I used the implicit function theorem and got

$$ \frac{dX}{ d \theta} =- \frac{X \sec^2 \theta -\frac{g X^2}{2 (110)^2} 2 \sec \theta ( \sec \theta \tan \theta)  } {\tan \theta - \frac{g \sec^2 \theta}{2 (110)^2} 2X }$$

Now the problem here is that I can't prove this function is in monotonic in terms of $\theta$ as the implicit derivative is a function of both $\theta$ and $X$.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to maximize. $X$ and $\theta$ are related by the equation. Do you want the maximal $X$ or $\theta$?

Comment: It is still not clear after the edit. If you have $0=f(\theta, X)$, then the maximum of $f$ is $0$.

Comment: I want  can vary theta and for that I want to find for which theta I can maximize X

Comment: I tried fixing it again

Comment: Just a comment about notation: Instead of writing $\tan \theta X$, it would be clearer if you wrote $X \tan \theta$ or $(\tan \theta)X$. See what I mean?

Comment: One way to understand the problem better is to draw a graph! I've changed $\theta \to x$, $X \to y$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s6c2jmpcvw . So graphically, the largest value is obtained at $\approx (0.832, 1~123.54)$

Comment: I did the correction, and I get it intuitively, but I can't reason it in mathematical words

Comment: The discriminant method gives the maximal $\theta$, not the maximal $X$ because when $\theta$ is slightly above its maximum, there is not solution $X$, so the discriminant is $<0$.

Comment: can you rephrase what you mean griboullious?

Comment: Use your last equation to eliminate $X$ from your first equation. Solve for $\theta$. Use that in your final equation to get $X$. The “discriminant method” is not correct. The maximum of $X$ doesn’t occur at the angle making the discriminant zero; it occurs at a greater angle.

Comment: @G.Smith please check the new addition to the qsn

Comment: $X$ *isn’t* monotonic over the region of $\theta$ where $D(\theta)$. Numerically plotting  the larger root of the quadratic will make this obvious to you.

Comment: where $ D(\theta)$ ...? I think there should be something else in that sentence. Oh,  now if it is monotonic then where would I find the inflection point?

Comment: I meant to write “where $D(\theta) >0$”. And you apparently meant to write “if it is *not* monotonic”.

Comment: Did you read my comment starting “Use your last equation...” about how to complete the calculation?

Comment: I did and I appreciate it, I am not trying to find the answer at this point. I'm trying to figure out why the answer turns out weird depending on the way I do it

Comment: You want to find a launch angle $\theta$ for maximum/ optimum  $X$, right?

Comment: I want to find optimum X, but indirectly , yes I need an optimum theta for best X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reworded the problem setting $X=y$ and $\theta=x$. Considering  $g=9.81$, solving the quadratic equation for $y$ gives the two solutions

$$\displaystyle y =-\frac{ 1100}{981} \cos x \\ \left(    \sqrt{10} \sqrt{121000 \tan^2 x - 20601 \sec^2 x} - 1100 \tan x     \right)$$

$$\displaystyle y =\frac{ 1100}{981} \cos x \\ \left(    \sqrt{10} \sqrt{121000 \tan^2 x - 20601 \sec^2 x} +1100 \tan x     \right)$$

The separate plots of the two functions are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20-1100%2F981%20cos%5E2%28x%29%20%28sqrt%2810%29%20sqrt%28121000%20tan%5E2%28x%29%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%28x%29%29%20-%201100%20tan%28x%29%29%2C%20%20x%3D0%20to%20%20pi%20) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%201100%2F981%20cos%5E2%28x%29%20%28sqrt%2810%29%20sqrt%28121000%20tan%5E2%28x%29%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%28x%29%29%20%2B%201100%20tan%28x%29%29%2C%20%20x%3D0%20to%20%20pi%20). The combined plot of the two functions is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+-1100%2F981+cos%5E2%28x%29+%28sqrt%2810%29+sqrt%28121000+tan%5E2%28x%29+-+20601+sec%5E2%28x%29%29+-+1100+tan%28x%29%29%2C++++++y+%3D+1100%2F981+cos%5E2%28x%29+%28sqrt%2810%29+sqrt%28121000+tan%5E2%28x%29+-+20601+sec%5E2%28x%29%29+%2B+1100+tan%28x%29%29%2C+++++++++++x%3D0+to++pi+).
By clarity, I also paste them here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The maximal value is achieved by the second function. Its [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%201100%2F981%20cos%5E2%28x%29%20%28sqrt%2810%29%20sqrt%28121000%20tan%5E2%28x%29%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%28x%29%29%20%2B%201100%20tan%28x%29%29%20derivative) is quite complicated, and a closed form for the value of $x$ that maximizes $y$ may probably not exist. However, as already noteď in the OP and in the comments,  the numerical solution is given by $x\approx 0.832$ radians (corresponding to about $47.67$ degrees), which leads to a maximum of $y\approx 1123.54$, as confirmed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Local%20maximum%20%20%201100%2F981%20cos%5E2%28x%29%20%28sqrt%2810%29%20sqrt%28121000%20tan%5E2%28x%29%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%28x%29%29%20%2B%201100%20tan%28x%29%29%20%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2). By a similar numerical assessment of the first function, it can be confirmed that the symmetrical minimum value of $y\approx -1123.54$ is achieved for $x\approx \pi-0.832\approx 2.309$ radians (corresponding to about $132.33$ degrees), as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Local%20minimum%20%20%20-1100%2F981%20cos%5E2%28x%29%20%28sqrt%2810%29%20sqrt%28121000%20tan%5E2%28x%29%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%28x%29%29%20-%201100%20tan%28x%29%29%20%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi).

Note that setting the determinant equal to zero, as cited by the OP, only gives the values of $x$ for which the values of the two functions coincide. These values, which have rather tricky [closed forms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=121000%20tan%5E2%20x%20-%2020601%20sec%5E2%20x%3D0) that can be approximated by $x\approx 0.4253$ and $\approx 2.7163$, correspond to the points where the two functions meet, in the leftmost and rightmost portion of the combined plot.

Comment: why are there separate plots for the function?

Comment: I separated them only for better clarity. They simply correspond to the two solutions obtained for $y$, after writing the equation in its explicit form.

Comment: wait discriminant gives completely wrong?

Comment: My friend had calculated it for me and found a near maxima thing but with different angle for it

Comment: The discriminant of the quadratic equation solving for $y$ is not particularly useful to find the maximum. The angle found by your friend ($0.425$ radians or $24.3$ degrees)  is that described at the end of my answer and gives the point where the two functions meet. It does not correspond to the maximum.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I tried plotting this function on wolf ram but it gave no graph, do you know why this might be?

Comment: Sometimes implicit plots are  not so easy to get using plotters (see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942653/wolfram-alpha-doesnt-plot-implicit-function-with-range).  Try to set the range, for example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Contourplot+y+tan+x+-+9.81%2F2++y%5E2+1%2Fcos%5E2+x+%2F110%5E2++-+105%3D0%2C+x%3D-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2%2C+y%3D-1300+to+1300

Answer (score 8):

This is a similar but simple approach which gives the same result. Seeing that $y=\tan(\theta)$ can take any positive value, we go for maximizing $x$ and get $\max(x) = 1123$.

We have: $105 = x\tan\theta-\frac{g}{2} \frac{x^2\sec^2\theta}{(110)^2}$

Let $\ a=105,\ y=\tan\theta,\ b = \frac{g}{2} \frac{1}{(110)^2}.\quad$  Then, $\ a=xy-bx^2(y^2+1)$

Taking $xy=c,\; x^2=\frac{c-bc^2-a}{b}$  (Note that since $y$ can take any positive value, so can $c$)

So, for $\,x_{\max},\quad \frac{d}{dc}\ (\frac{c-bc^2-a}{b}) = 0$ which gives $c=\frac{1}{2b}$

Now, $x_{\max} = \sqrt{\frac{c-bc^2-a}{b}}\quad at\, c=\frac{1}{2b},$ i.e. $\,x_{\max} \approx 1123$ by plugging in values of $a$ and $b.$

Comment: that's a very weird substitution , can you like give motivation behind the substution's you choose?

Comment: crazy method bro.. my mind is blown. How did you discover this?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it worked still but Idk why, can you give a brief explanation of what exactly did you did?

Comment: I'm still confused the derivative with c step, because like c=xy, so I don't know the differential of that would look. And why are we optimizing x with respect to c?

Comment: Yes sure. Basically, we can 'play' with this quantity c=xy since c can take on any positive value for all non-zero x because y can take any positive value ($0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}2$). Since c is now just any new variable, we have a relationship between x and c. This allows for maximizing x by taking it's derivative with respect to c. Hope that gives some insight!

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track; you just didn't go far enough. Your first equation relating $X$ and $\theta$ is

$$0=X\tan\theta-\frac{g}{2v^2}X^2\sec^2\theta-h\tag1$$

where I've written $h$ for the height of the cliff and $v$ for the initial velocity of the projectile in your [original question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565783/finding-max-horizontal-distance-to-be-able-to-strike-target-in-projectile-motion) posted to Physics SE.

(Why did you put in numbers for $h$ and $v$ but not for $g$? Why put in numbers at all, when you can get a nice general formula for any values of these parameters? Why were your values inconsistent between your physics post at your post here?)

You wanted the point on the $X(\theta$) curve that maximizes $X$. As you realized, this is the point where $dX/d\theta=0$.

You *could* solve (1), which is quadratic in $X$, for $X$ in terms of $\theta$ and then differentiate, set the derivative to zero, solve for $\theta$, and put that back in to find the maximum $X$. This works but involves more algebra than the better approach that you took involving implicit differentiation. You differentiated (1) and set $dX/d\theta$ to $0$, finding

$$\frac{v^2}{g\tan\theta}=X\tag2.$$

The maximum point on the $X(\theta)$ curve satisfies *both* (1) and (2): (1) because it is a point on the curve, and (2) because it is the *maximum* point. So you need to solve these two *simultaneous* equations.

This is straightforward: First use (2) to eliminate $X$ from (1), giving an equation involving only $\theta$:

$$0=\left(\frac{v^2}{g\tan\theta}\right)\tan\theta-\frac{g}{2v^2}\left(\frac{v^2}{g\tan\theta}\right)^2\sec^2\theta-h$$

which simplifies to

$$0=\frac{v^2}{g}-\frac{v^2}{2g}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-h.$$

It's easy to solve this for the value of $\theta$ at the maximum point:

$$\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-2q}}$$

where $q\equiv gh/v^2$.

From this one finds that

$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{1-2q}{2-2q}}$$

and

$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2q}}.$$

Substituting this into (2) gives the value of $X$ at the maximum point,

$$X=\frac{v^2}{g}\sqrt{1-\frac{2gh}{v^2}}.$$

Putting in the values $h=105\text{ m}$, $v=110\text{ m/s}^2$, and $g=9.81\text{ m/s}^2$ gives $X=1123.54$ m.

Note that simply completing your solution in this straightforward way does not require the clever substitution that Anonymous used.

Setting the discriminant of (1) to zero does *not* give the position of the maximum point on the $X(\theta)$ curve. Instead, as Anatoly's graphs show, it gives the point where the two solutions for $X$ coincide. It is also clear from those graphs that the upper solution with the maximum is *not* monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to write a quadratic in terms of $ \tan \theta $ and not in terms of $X$

$$ 0 =  X \tan \theta -\frac{g}{2} \frac{ X^2 (1 +\tan^2 \theta)}{(110)^2} - 105$$

applying the condition that tangent $ D>0$ for the quadratic in terms of $ \tan \theta$(taking g as 10),

I get, this

$$ 1> \frac{20}{(110)^2} ( 105 + \frac{5X^2}{(110)^2})$$

$$ -1100 < X<1100$$

Taking the upper bound, it becomes $X=1100$

Comment: Why use a trick when none is required and the trick wouldn't work in a more general case, such as when the equation is not quadratic in $\tan\theta$? It is much more useful to learn general methods that always work.

Comment: I agree a 100% , but I just wanted to understand what my friend was trying to tell me :)) Thank you for the support, mr.smith

Answer (score 1):

By letting $u = \tan \theta \in (0, \infty)$, the equation is written as
$$\frac{g}{2} \frac{  X^2 (1+u^2) }{ (110)^2 } - X u + 105 = 0.$$
The equation has real roots if and only if its discriminant is non-negative, that is,
$D = \frac{(110^2 - 210 g) u^2  - 210 g}{110^2} \ge 0$ (equivalently, $u \ge \sqrt{\frac{210g}{110^2 - 210g}}$).
Also, if $D \ge 0$, the equation has two positive real roots (by Vieta's formulas), given by
\begin{align}
X_1 &= \frac{110^2 u + 110^2\sqrt{D}}{g(u^2+1)}, \\
X_2 &= \frac{110^2 u - 110^2\sqrt{D}}{g(u^2+1)}.
\end{align}
Clearly, we should choose the larger root, that is,
$$X = X_1 = \frac{110^2 (u + \sqrt{D})}{g(u^2+1)}.$$
Clearly, if $D > 0$ (equivalently, $u > \sqrt{\frac{210g}{110^2 - 210g}}$), then $X$ is differentiable with
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} X}{\mathrm{d} u} &= \frac{110^2}{g}
\cdot \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{D}}\frac{\mathrm{d} D}{\mathrm{d} u})(u^2+1) - 
(u+\sqrt{D})\cdot 2u}{(u^2+1)^2}\\
&= \frac{110^2}{g(u^2+1)^2}
\left(1 - u^2 + \left(\frac{(110^2-210g)u(u^2+1)}{110^2 D} - 2u\right)\sqrt{D}\right).
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d} X}{\mathrm{d} u} = 0 \\
\Longrightarrow \quad & u^2 - 1 = \left(\frac{(110^2-210g)u(u^2+1)}{110^2 D} - 2u\right)\sqrt{D}\\
\Longrightarrow \quad & (u^2 - 1)^2 = \left(\frac{(110^2-210g)u(u^2+1)}{110^2 D} - 2u\right)^2D \\
\Longrightarrow \quad & \frac{210g}{110^4 D}(u^2+1)^2(110^2-(110^2-210g)u^2) = 0\\
\Longrightarrow \quad & u = \frac{110}{\sqrt{110^2 - 210g}}.
\end{align}
Comparing $X(\sqrt{\frac{210g}{110^2 - 210g}})$, $X(\frac{110}{\sqrt{110^2 - 210g}})$ and $X(\infty)$, we know that
$X$ achieves its maximum $\frac{110}{g}\sqrt{110^2-210g}$ at $u = \frac{110}{\sqrt{110^2 - 210g}}$.

For $g = 9.81$, $X$ achieves its maximum $1123.539567$ at $\theta = 47.66952494^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed directly.. straightforward way. We have the given relation $ (x=X)$:

$$105 = x\tan\theta-\frac{g}{2} \dfrac{x^2\sec^2\theta}{(110)^2} \tag1 $$

To facilitate differentiation let us use symbols for the time being

$$\ h=105,\ V=110 , \tan\theta =t,\dfrac{2v^2}{g}=a \tag2 $$

$$ xt-x^2(1+t^2)/a -h =0 \tag3$$

We need to do ***implicit differentiation*** of the ***fourth order polynomial*** because $x,t$ are involved together.

Priming with respect to $t$ as independent variable

$$x^{'} t + x -\big[ 2x/a \cdot (1+t^2) \cdot x ^{'}  +x^2/a \cdot 2t \big]=0 \tag4 $$

Set $x^{'}=0 $ to find maximum $x,$ and simplify cancelling $x$ on LHS getting

$$ x= \dfrac{a}{2t}\tag5 $$

From (3) and (5) we can find $(t,\theta) $. Plugging this into (3) and simplifying

$$\dfrac{1+t^2}{t^2}=\dfrac{2a-4h}{a} \tag6 $$

$$\dfrac{t^2}{1}=\dfrac{a}{a-4h}\rightarrow t = \tan \theta =\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a-4h}} =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2gh/V^2}}\tag7 $$

Plugging this into (5)

$$x_{max}=\dfrac{a}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{a-4h}{a}} = \dfrac{V^2}{g} {\sqrt{1-2gh/V^2}} \tag8 $$

You can verify sign of second derivative to check it is maximum. To check for *the special case*

$$ h=0, \; x_{max}= \dfrac{a}{2}= \dfrac{V^2}{g}\tag9 $$

a well known result in projectile motion that the maximum range is double the height reached when projected vertically at angle $\theta =\pi/2 $ to horizontal.

For this particular case put $h=0$ in (7) to tally $ \theta = 45^{\circ} $ okay.

With given *numerical values* $\; V=110, \; g=9.81,\; h=105,$ we calculate

$$ X_{optimum}=1123.54,\;\theta_{optimum}=46.67^{\circ} \tag {10}$$

Projectile parabolic trajectories are shown below to scale.

By increasing and decreasing $\theta$ by $\pm 30^{\circ} $ the  blue, green parabolas should cut $ y=h=105\;$ at  values lower than 1123.54  for an optimum $X_m$ red parabola to be valid.. a fact that is graphically also verified.

[image]