# Different methods of maximum distance of projectile motion giving different answer

Tags: calculus, physics, projection, kinematics

Consider a time independent projectile motion thrown from the ground from a height of zero:

$$ y = x \tan \theta - \frac{g}{2v_o^2} \sec^2 \theta x^2$$

Where $x$ is a horizontal range, $y$ is the height for a given $x$ and $ \theta$ is the angle which the projectile is thrown at it, $u_x$ and $u_Yy$ are horizontal and vertical velocities respectively.

**Figuring out maximum height using implicit function theorem:**

$ (x_{max} , 0)$ is a solution to the above curve, (ground is reference):

$$F= 0 = y_o + x_{max} \tan \theta - \frac{g}{2 v_o^2} \sec^2 \theta x^2$$

Now, apply the implicit function theorem:

$$ \frac{dx}{d \theta} =-  \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}}{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}$$

For optimum conditions,

$$ \frac{ \partial F}{\partial \theta} = 0$$

Or,

$$ 0=x_{max}  \sec^2 \theta  - \frac{g}{2 v_o^2} 2 \sec^2 \theta \tan \theta x_{max}^2$$

Simplifying

$$ 0 = 1 - \frac{g}{v_o^2} \tan \theta x_{max}^2$$

$$ \sqrt{\frac{ v_o^2}{g \tan \theta} }= x_{max}$$

Seems so that there is no real 'optimal' angle of throw, you can make theta as small as you want to make the projectile go further.

**Another way:**

The time of flight is given as:

$$ t = 2 \frac{u_y}{g}$$

And, the horizontal displacement equation:

$$ x_{max} = u_x t =\frac{ 2 u_y u_x}{g}$$

Now, my question is why does each way give a different answer? Are they both right or have I made a mistake somewhere?

[Related question by me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756436/optimizing-a-quadratic-in-one-variable-with-parameterized-coefficients/3759508#3759508)

[References for equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)

Comment: Don't mess up with envelope which is the boundary of safe zone.

Comment: @NgChungTak Could you explain what you mean a bit more specifically?

Comment: Try to search lawn sprinkler in my answers first.  There're limitions for me using mobile now.

Comment: Thank you, I will see @NgChungTak