# Graph of $\sqrt{(x - y)} = 0$

Tags: graphing-functions

is there some reason why the graph of $\sqrt{(x-y)} = 0$ wouldn't be equal to the graph of $x = y$?

The reason why i'm asking this is that in GeoGebra, when i plot $\sqrt{(x-y)} = 0$, i don't get any points.

Thanks!

Comment: Being unfamiliar with Geogebra, my **blind guess** is rounding error.

Comment: Funny.  Seems to stump [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+sqrt%28x-y%29%3D0) too.  On the other hand, WA can handle [$\sqrt {x-y}=1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+sqrt%28x-y%29%3D1) .

Comment: Desmos reacts the same.

Comment: From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942653/wolfram-alpha-doesnt-plot-implicit-function-with-range?rq=1) "*Most numerical implicit function plotters actually depend on recognizing changes of sign. Basically, if you want to plot f(x,y)=0, you start by sampling a bunch of points f(xi,yj), and you know that if this has opposite signs at two neighbouring points, there should be a piece of the curve somewhere between them.*" (@RobertIsrael)  This seems to be the same case here, we can never have difference of sign because $\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ for all valid $x$.

Comment: It also explains why it can handle $\sqrt{x-y}=1$ as there are values of $x,y$ such that it is less than $1$ and other values such that it is more than $1$.